# which is best for blender rendering cpu or gpu

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, hardware

I am trying to learn Blender , my current system with i5 3230M with 8GB works all right but struggling , So I am planning to build a budget pc. It ll be really helpful if you anyone could help me out on important question . is it best to have a good cpu (like i7 7700) and no graphics or to have mediocre cpu (like Ryzen 3 1200) and a graphics card (like GTX 1050Ti 8GB).

I read cpu can take advantage of copious ram for large scenes and gpu can be faster under normal rendering circumstances.

Any suggestions save for a particular cpu or gpu , Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For learning your old setup is quite ok. When it comes to rendering it depends on the scene as you already noticed, so there is no definitive answer to your question...

Comment: Hardware recommendations, discussions about brands or models are considered off topic. Please read the following link: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic

Comment: sorry for posting a off-topic question , will be more careful in posting questions in future thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d go pure cpu for now, it’s quite easy to max a gpu’s 4-6gb ram cap

Whilst you can upgrade normal system ram

Plus cpu’s Are closing the gap substantially on GPUs in blender

To put it into perspective:
Amd’s Threadripper 1950x £800 can render a scene at 90% the speed of a gp100 Nvidia gpu (£4000 card 16gb cap) but if the scene gets over that 16gn limit then and wins hands down

Check this http://download.blender.org/institute/benchmark/latest_snapshot.html